# celery class-based Task is not retring when autoretry_for is set

Tags: python, django, celery

Celery class-based task is not retiring automatically when `autoretry_for` is configured.

```py
import celery

class SaveImageUrl(celery.Task):
    autoretry_for = (TypeError,)
    retry_kwargs = {'max_retries': 5, 'countdown': 5}


    def run(self, message_id: str) -> None:
        ...
        raise TypeError


SaveImageUrl = app.register_task(SaveImageUrl())  # here app is celery app


#calling task
SaveImageUrl.apply_async(args=(1,))
```

However, this works for function-based task:

```py
@shared_task(bind=True, autoretry_for=(TypeError,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 3, 'countdown': 2})
def save_image_url(self, message_id: str):
    ...
    raise TypeError


#calling task
save_image_url.apply_async(args=(1,))
```

Celery Version : `4.4`